# How to test if two Integer[] arrays are equal

Tags: java, testing, junit

so i need to determine if an Integer[] expResult is equal to an Integer[] result, i tried to use assertTrue and assertEquals but they will not work.. 
if someone could help me it would be very nice! thanks

Comment: Have you tried [java.util.Arrays.equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use assertArrayEquals like:

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1,2,3},new int[]{1,2,3});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as

```
Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(a), Arrays.asList(b));
```